# How to set cell-color according to cell-value on ooo-calc?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, openoffice-calc

I can change the style of a cell using conditional formatting. But there I would be limited to a maximum of 3 cases it can handle.

What I want to do is to get the value of a cell, convert it in a certain way and set the result as the cells background-color.

The simplest example would be cells with values between 0 and 10, resulting in gray-steps between white and black.

Is this possible? Are there ways to set the background-color of a cell automatically?

Thx!

Comment: As far as I can see conditional formatting in OOo cannot do that. Excel has no problems there, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey) said: "As far as I can see conditional formatting in OOo cannot do that. Excel has no problems there, though."
It's simply not possible... :-/

Answer (score 4):

This has been implemented in libreoffice 3.6 ([see the release notes](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/3-6-new-features-and-fixes))

Comment: Ah answered the exact same day Libre 3.6 was released, so quick!

Answer (score 2):

Format one cell how you want (not one you want to conditionally format).

Press F11 to get the Styles dialogue box

Use the button one from the top right, which is "New Style From Selection"

Type the name you want, e.g. BlackBack

Then do the conditional formatting of the relevant cells, choosing BlackBack

---

Source: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=61294

Note that you can find "Conditional Formatting" under the Format menu in OOo Calc.